# Can I default the first template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a template method with two typename parameters (it's actually `QObject::connect()` - see [this answer](/a/38783518) and [another answer](/a/37302949)).  Because the typenames are for member pointers, deduction can fail when the name passed in refers to an overloaded function; when that happens, we need to either coerce one argument to the correct type (perhaps by storing it into a local variable of the desired type) or to qualify the call with one or more of the template parameters.

Taking an example from a one of the linked questions:

```
QObject::connect(spinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged,
                 slider, &QSlider::setValue);
```

needs to be written as

```
QObject::connect<void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(spinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged,
                                         slider, &QSlider::setValue);
```

or (by coercing):

```
void(QSpinBox::*signal)(int) = &QSpinBox::valueChanged;
QObject::connect(spinBox, signal,
                 slider, &QSlider::setValue);
```

Sometimes, though, the first template argument could be deduced, but a later one is required.  Is there an easy way to default the first parameter, but specify others?  I was thinking of something like

```
QObject::connect<auto, void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged,
                                               spinBox, &QSpinBox::setValue);
```

Obviously, that's not valid C++, but I hope it illustrates the point.

I know I can write

```
void(QSpinBox::*slot)(int) = &QSpinBox::setValue;
QObject::connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged,
                 spinBox, slot);
```

but I'm hoping for a more concise syntax.

Comment: I think you should be able to cast the function into the pointer type you want with a static cast.  Something like `static_cast<void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(QSpinBox::setValue)`.  That should allow template argument deduction to work so you do not need to specify the type.

Comment: Well, that's even uglier - I prefer to define a sensible `up_cast<>()` that's safer (and also useful for coercing the arguments of `?:` without narrowing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to default the first parameter, but specify others?

No. You'll just have to coerce the second argument manually, like with a `static_cast`:

```
QObject::connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged,
    spinBox, static_cast<void(QSpinBox::*)(int)>(&QSpinBox::setValue));
```

Or just use a different overload of `connect()` and pass a lambda:

```
QObject::connect(slider, &QSlider::valueChanged,
    [&spinBox](int i){ spinBox.setValue(i); });
```

Comment: I suspected the answer was probably "no", but it seemed worth asking.  I'll stick with the local variable approach as the cleanest, then.

Comment: @TobySpeight Not a fan of the lambda approach?

Comment: Not especially, but that's subjective.  I wouldn't object to it in a code review, but I'd rarely write it myself either.  Probably I'm imagining far more overhead than such lambdas actually incur!  You do need to be careful here, as you've subtly changed the connection type argument from 'auto' to 'direct' - that's not a problem in UI->UI connections such as this, but can be problematic cross-thread.